# command line and Node.js communication (without closing)

Tags: node.js, ipc

I've been looking at the [documentation](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest-v11.x/api/child_process.html) but I can't find a way to pass commands to the command line (cmd.exe) without closing it at the end. How can I communicate the command line 'continuously'?

I noticed the fork function but it seems to be only for node.js modules..

```
const { spawn } = require('child_process');
const ls = spawn('C:\\Windows\\System32\\cmd', ['/c', 'echo hello']);

ls.stdout.on('data', (data) => {
  console.log(`stdout: ${data}`);
});

ls.stderr.on('data', (data) => {
  console.log(`stderr: ${data}`);
});

ls.on('close', (code) => {
  console.log(`child process exited with code ${code}`);
});
```

Results in:

```
stdout: hello

child process exited with code 0 // I dont want it to exit yet!
```

Answer (score 0):

It is quite trivial in the end. Just spawn the program and write into its `stdin`:

```
const { spawn } = require('child_process');
const child = spawn('C:\\Windows\\System32\\cmd.exe');

child.stdin.write('echo IM BACK\n');

child.stdout.on('data', (data) => {
    console.log(`command line says:\n${data}`);
});
```

produces:

```
c:\Users\...\03 cmd.exe communcation>
command line says:
echo IM BACK
IM BACK
```

one might also add 'echo off'